# Converting Command Curl into PHP curl

Tags: php, curl

I would like to convert the following command CURL into P is there an online convert? or can someone explain how to convert please

```
curl "http://nseindia.com/products/dynaContent/equities/indices/historicalindices.jsp?indexType=CNX"%"20NIFTY&fromDate=27-07-2015&toDate=27-07-2015"
<p>-H "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8"</p>
<p>-H "Cache-Control: max-age=0"</p>
<p>-H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch"</p>
<p>-H "Proxy-Connection: keep-alive"</p>
<p>-H "Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6"</p>
<p>-H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.134 Safari/537.36"</p>
<p>--compressed</p>
```

i have added the p tag to make it look clean please ignore it.

Comment: Is `P` short for PHP? If so here's a link for your reading, http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php. I know of no online too to convert this and recommendation for such are off-topic for this site. If you have specific coding questions/issues that would be on-topic.

Answer (score 1):

This is it converted to PHP, you can use the options `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` to set custom request headers.

```
$curl = curl_init();
$headers = array(
    'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Cache-Control: max-age=0',
    'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch',
    'Proxy-Connection: keep-alive',
    'Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6'
);
$opts = array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'http://nseindia.com/products/dynaContent/equities/indices/historicalindices.jsp?indexType=CNX"%"20NIFTY&fromDate=27-07-2015&toDate=27-07-2015',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.134 Safari/537.36',
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers
);
curl_setopt_array($curl, $opts);
$response = curl_exec($curl);
```

Answer (score 1):

Below code will create a request just as yours, if you need more curl options have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

```
$headers = [
 "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
 "Cache-Control: max-age=0",
 "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch",
 "Proxy-Connection: keep-alive",
 "Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6",
 "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.134 Safari/537.36"];

$ch = curl_init('http://nseindia.com/products/dynaContent/equities/indices/historicalindices.jsp?indexType=CNX"%"20NIFTY&fromDate=27-07-2015&toDate=27-07-2015');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.134 Safari/537.36');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING , "");
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```